# Communication Between JS/HTML in Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make my first Chrome Extension without any prior JS knowledge, and I have some trouble doing it.

**What does the extension do?**

It's a page action extension for generating a string and copying it to the clipboard. The string includes certain element attributes from the DOM.

**Scope**

It's only applicable on two pages (the domains below are examples):

1. https://xxx.abc.com/CFM/Messages/CFMEWFA/*
2. https://xxx.abc.com/CFM/Messages/FraudPrevention/*

**Elements of the extension**

The extension has a **popup.html** with three clickable options to be chosen at the user's discretion:

- No response
- Invalid
- Valid

The string is formatted based on the user's choice from the popup, and whether the tab URL contains "CFMEWFA" or "FraudPrevention".

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <ul id="MENU">
    <li id="MENUnoResponse"><a href="#">No reponse</a>
    </li>
    <li id="MENUinValid"><a href="#">Invalid</a>
    </li>
    <li id="MENUvalid"><a href="#">Valid</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

**popup.js** is supposed to listen for clicks in popup.html, employ a multi item clickhandler, then message background.js at the event of a click. The message should include an argument corresponding to the li id in popup.html.

**popup.js**

```
var theParentMenu = document.querySelector("#MENU");
theParentMenu.addEventListener("click", userHasClicked, false);

function userHasClicked(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    var clickedItem = e.target.id;
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      directive: e.target.id
    }, function(response) {
      this.close();
    });
  };
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

**background.js** is governing where the extension icon is shown. It also listens for messages from popup.js (containing an argument determined by the user's choice from popup.html) before executing **content.js**, a script which runs in the tab.url fetching attributes from the DOM and generating the string. I have yet to start building content.js because of unresolved issues earlier in other files.

**background.js**

```
//Displays the page action extension only on specific pages
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

    if (tab.url.indexOf("https://xxx.abc.com/CFM/Messages/FraudPrevention/") == 0) 
        {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        }
    else if (tab.url.indexOf("https://xxx.abc.com/CFM/Messages/CFMEWFA/") == 0) 
        {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
        }
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl)


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {
        case "MENUnoReponse":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                //file: "contentscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                //allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
        case "MENUinValid":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                //file: "contentscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                //allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
        case "MENUvalid":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                //file: "contentscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                //allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender

            break;
        default:
            // helps debug when request directive doesn't match
            alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to background.js from " + sender);
        }
    }
);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "EW logger",
  "description": "This extension creates logs for early warning and fraud prevention cases",
  "version": "1.0",

  "page_action": {
    "default_title": "EW",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "https://xxx.abc.com/*"
  ]

}
```

**What works:**

- The extension icon appears like it should.

**My problems:**

- The options in popup.html are not working. Popup.js doesn't do anything when I click.

Do you have any suggestion to how I can "listen" for clicks in popup.html properly, and then send a message containing an argument to background.js?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running before the body is loaded, so the element is not found. You can fix this by moving the script tag to the bottom of the body. Alternatively, use `<script src="popup.js" defer></script>` to delay execution until the dom is loaded.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer

Also, you should use console.log(message) and the Chrome Devtools console to debug and check for errors.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I've almost completed the extension now, but a new issue presented itself.

I have a string stored in a variable, and I want this variable to be written to the clipboard automatically. document.execCommand('copy') seems to require an event. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Not sure, you can ask a new question about that.